# WPF version of Silverlight GetResourceStream

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Does WPF have something that does the same as Silverlight's

```
public static StreamResourceInfo GetResourceStream(
    StreamResourceInfo zipPackageStreamResourceInfo, Uri uriResource)
```

> Returns a resource file from a location in the specified zip package.

as the Windows version of this function does this:

> Returns a resource stream for a resource data file that is located at the specified Uri

Basically I want to read files from within a zip file without having to extract them all first, which I think is what the silverlight version of the function can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into SharpZipLib [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9ce6c242-c14c-4969-9251-af95e4cf320f/zip--unzip-folders-and-f.aspx), [here](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx) and for an alternative [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx).